# Let f,g be bounded measurable functions on a set E of finite measure. Show that: If f=a.e.g then ∫f=∫g

Tags: measure-theory

Let f,g be bounded measurable functions on a set E of finite measure. Show that:

If f=a.e.g then ∫f=∫g on E

I have this proof from Cupta book, but I can't understand how this step done, depends on what?

[image]

Comment: The integral preserves order. If $\phi$ dominates $f-g$ and the latter is a.e. zero, then $\phi$ is a.e. nonnegative, and hence the integral is nonnegative.

Comment: Thanks alot. But I confused about why integral of (f-g) must be nonnegative?

Comment: @DuaaHamzeh $f-g=0$ a.e., so $f-g$ is non-negative a.e. I dont like the proof of this book, it is complicated without any sense

Comment: Again. The domination property. If $u \leq v$ a.e. then the intergal of $u$ is less than or equal to that of $v$. This follows from saying if $v-u \leq 0$ a.e. then $\int v-u \leq 0.$ Prove this with an approximation argument.

Comment: Perhaps also share what Theorem 2.2 (b) is?

Comment: He conclude from "integral of  ϕ is nonnegative" so "integral of (f-g) nonnegative also" . But I can't understand why the first gives the second.

Comment: @Duaa, I have given an explanation for this already. Consult another source for properties of the integral relating to order.

Answer (score 0):

Let's prove this: Suppose $f \geq 0$ on a measurable set $E.$ Then $\int_E f \geq 0.$

Choose a simple function $u$ supported on $E$ so $u \leq f$ and $u \geq 0.$ Then

$$ \int_E u = \sum u_j m(E_j) $$

where $m$ is Lebesgue measure, $u_j \geq 0$, and the $E_j$ is a partition of $E$. Then the above is nonnegative. It follows that the supremum over all simple functions $u$ that approximate $f$ from below is nonnegative, and hence $\int_E f \geq 0.$

The result that $f \leq g$ a.e. on $E$ implies $\int_E f \leq \int_E g$ follows by replacing $f$ with $g-f$ in the above.